# What is a presentation of a group?

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation

I have read the following:

> $\left< a | a^n = 1 \right>$ may be written by $\left< a | a^{n}
>  \right>$ thanks to the convention that terms that do not include an
>   equals sign are taken to be equal to the group identity. Such terms
>   are called relators, distinguishing them from the relations that do
>   include an equals sign.

This paragraph is way too confusing; for example $1$ and $2$ are thus terms without an equal sign in $\mathbb{Z}/3$ how are they equal to the group identity? does anyone have a real definition I can read because I would appreciate it thanks.----

Comment: The group $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ would be presented as $\langle a \mid a^{3} \rangle$. The point of a presentation is that the group is given in terms of a set of generators (as a multiplicative group).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual definition of a presentation is that $\left< G\mid R\right>$ stands for the quotient of the free group over the set $G$ quotiented by the normal closure of the set $R$.

The rough definition is that elements of the resulting group are going to be words in the alphabet $G$, subject to the relations present in $R$ (any element of $R$ is set to equal the identity).

Answer (score 0):

> for example $1$ and $2$ are thus terms without an equal sign in $\Bbb Z/3$ how are they equal to the group identity?

They're not since they're neither relations nor relators.

Comment: Which 'terms with/without an equal sign' is the quotation referring to??

Comment: They mean, @7einadh, that the generators multiply in such a way that they become the identity; for instance, with $\Bbb Z_5=\langle a\mid a^5\rangle$, the order of $a$ is five, *i.e.*, $a^5= aaaaa=e$.

Comment: I am sorry but I do not see what two inequal elements in that are called relators - is it that $a$ and $aaaaa$ are not equal yet $aaaaa$ is the identity after the cycling process? I thought that was a ' relation '.

Comment: If it's written $a^5$, it's a relator; if $a^5=e$, it's a relation, @7einadh. Does that help? Another example would be $$\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z\cong\langle x,y\mid xy=yx\rangle,$$ which is written in terms of a relation, whereas, equivalently, we could have $$\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z\cong\langle x,y\mid xyx^{-1}y^{-1}\rangle,$$ which is written is terms of a relator.

Comment: Yes thanks very much.

Comment: You're welcome. Typically, people thank users for answers by upvoting them, @7einadh.

Comment: Oh: You haven't unlocked that feature yet. Sorry!